# dotnet run not serving static assets of dependencies

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I have a problem with `dotnet run` and static assets (contentFiles). I have a nuget package (built in my CI) that only contains CSS files to be used in other projects.

The 'other project' I'm talking about is a blazorwasm app that should use these css styles. The problem I have is:

- when I start the blazorwasm app with `dotnet run` (which starts a Kestrel Server to serve the compiles files I suppose?) the content Files of the nuget with the CSS are **not** served and lead to a 404 (referred by "css/theme.min.css").
- when I use 'dotnet publish' and start a nginx docker to serve it, the files are server (and stored at wwwroot/css of course)

Since I always used dotnet run to test my blazor apps before - and never had such a problem - I am a bit puzzled.

The nuspec of the nuget package is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd" >
  <metadata minClientVersion="3.3">
    <id>WebTheme</id>
    <title>Web Theme</title>
    <version>0.1.10</version>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <copyright>Copyright 2022</copyright>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/wwwroot/css/*" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false"/>
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="dist/css/theme.css" target="contentFiles/any/any/wwwroot/css" />
    <file src="dist/css/theme.css.map" target="contentFiles/any/any/wwwroot/css" />
    <file src="dist/css/theme.min.css" target="contentFiles/any/any/wwwroot/css" />
    <file src="dist/css/theme.min.css.map" target="contentFiles/any/any/wwwroot/css" />
    <file src="dist/css/theme.css" target="content/wwwroot/css" />
    <file src="dist/css/theme.css.map" target="content/wwwroot/css" />
    <file src="dist/css/theme.min.css" target="content/wwwroot/css" />
    <file src="dist/css/theme.min.css.map" target="content/wwwroot/css" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Program.cs of the target application:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using ManagementApp;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

builder.Services.AddOptions();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Comment: Could you please share your `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs` file in case of `dotnet-6`, another thing is does your `css` belongs under `wwwroot` folder?

Comment: You could keep your static files under the Root folder. The default directory is `{content root}/wwwroot`, but it can be changed with the [UseWebRoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingabstractionswebhostbuilderextensions.usewebroot) method. If your static files are located outside the root folder then you could refer to [Serve files outside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root).

Comment: I added the Program.cs.

I would say my css belongs under the wwwroot folder? The problem is, the contentFiles of the Nuget are not copied to the {content root}/wwwroot folder - which is quite right imho - but when using `dotnet run` the contents of `bin\Debug\net6.0\wwwroot` folder are not served via kestrel. Although the contentFiles of the Nuget are extracted in this folder.

Comment: Okay.. It seems to have something todo with the UseStaticFiles() Method - which is not available in WebAssembly :/ - That said.. I also have a Razor Pages Project where the css files of the nuget are not delivered aswell.

Comment: Go to your `Program.cs` file. Add `app.UseStaticFiles();` before `app.Run();`. Add your files to `wwwroot` folder and try to run your project. See whether you are able to see the static file.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Sadly it seems that UseStaticFiles() is not supported on blazorwasm projects (as they are just compiled static files anyways) and my blazor-server app already has that enabled :/ 

Anyways I seem to have found a solution to my problem - will post an answer myself today or tomorrow